# How to secure the product list endpoint for a Ecommerce api?

Tags: node.js, api, authentication, jwt, endpoint

Am creating api for ecommerce website and app using nodejs
We have a list Of Api routs and each rout have multiple endpoints
Consider am using authentication such as JWT for accessing those end points, so that all endpoint can be accessed only after authentication.

But some of the end points such as product listing, searching, etc should be accessed with out authentication because while loading the page those things should be displayed.

So am giving exception for those endpoints using "Unless" in JWT.

This makes the api endpoint for product listing open and any one can access it.

Whether this is correct?
If not what is the best approach for handling this scenario?

Frontend:
Flutter for mobile application
Reactjs for web application

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 approaches :

1. securing your APIs with authentication and authorization methods (like you said JWT or OAuth2)
2. IP whitelisting

in first approach you can do something else,generate and store some tokens like Client-Key and give them to your trusted clients and make an authorization system to check if the person is making a request to your endpoints sends it to you and you check if that client-key is belong to that person and he is a trusted client that really can access your endpoints (even public or private ones),you should consider that client-key will never change,in the next step you can authenticate users with JWT and etc.

in second approach you restrict access to the API by allowing only specific IP addresses.